# How to make sure URL bar is not hidden when scrolling to top in mobile safari

Tags: jquery, mobile, safari, scroll, jquery-animate

In a smallscreen stylesheet, I would like to scroll to the top of the page with jQuery (not jQuery mobile).

```
// scroll to top
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');
```

Now this works, but it goes all the way up and hides the URL Bar. And it produces a behaviour that when you pull the content back down (to see the URL bar), it jumps right up again and hides the URL bar again.

I would like it to scroll to the top of the page without hiding the URL bar. Is that possible?

Other similar questions rather tend to want the URL bar to disappear to generate WebAppFeel. This is just for a smallscreen stylesheet for a website and so I would like the URL bar to stay where it is.